# Careers: Not able to save an Experience entry

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, ajax, experience

For completing my Careers profile, I wanted to add my Experience entries. After a click on the save-button, nothing happens.

In the Chrome-console, the following AJAX error is stated:

```
POST http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/section/updatesection/0?cvId=0 404 (NotFound)
```

Looks like the user ID is absent from the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about that Michael.  Had a hiccup in some javascript I deployed last night.  All should be fixed now.  Thanks for the report!